# Javascript function visible on newform.aspx page in developer tool but not visible on SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript

I an debugging a SharePoint 2010 New form page and in developer tool I can see a function written under `<script> //[CDATA]` tag. But when I open the Newform.aspx in Designer I don't find that particular function on the page. Neither the function is available in the associated Master Page. Also no content editor web part on the page.

Would like to know from where this script is coming? Is there any other way the scripts shows in Developer tool in NewForm.aspx but not visible when actually opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in a CDATA section in the BODY it is most likely a User Custom Action with a ScriptBlock setting instead of a ScriptSrc

```
<CustomAction
  Location="ScriptLink"
  ScriptBlock="alert('hello');" 
  Sequence="100">
```

Adding a Custom Action to a Display Form: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh500259(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: its like this <script type= text/javascript>

//<![CDATA[

function XYZ(){}

//]]>

</script>

seems the CDATA part is commented

Comment: Yes, CustomAction ScriptBlock is wrapped in a CDATA tag; it does execute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag